# Getting a JSON string response from web method

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, json.net, jsonserializer

In my web application there is a WCF web service. In the following method

```
public string GetPolicyDetails(GetPolicyDetails_ML ml)
{

    var strFileName = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        "log.xml");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetPolicyDetails", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policy_id", ml.policyID);
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,Formatting.Indented);
        return json;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return "fail";
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

will return a json string inWCF Test Client. I need to access this method from my tab application. The code i used is

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
var  ds = await client.GetPolicyInfoAsync(Convert.ToInt16(txtPolicyNumber.Text));
```

This will get the response in to the #var ds#. My question is what is the type of this var ds and how to get the Json data out of this variable ds. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any `GetPolicyInfoAsync` in the sample provided.As of what provided, the return value of of type `string` and you need to `deserialize` this string to get your `DataTable` back.And what's the purpose of `DataSet ` variable  you declared?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh When it is accessed to method in the tab application it gives it as `GetPolicyInfoAsync` .ds was declared to store the return of the method. Datatables are not usable in tab applications I think. Can you suggest me a way get a datatable data through a website and use it in tab application, thank you

Comment: Did you generated `async` methods in the client?

Comment: `var ds` will be of whatever type `GetPolicyInfoAsync` returns.